# How to select item from model when SelectedItem is used to binding in database?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

i using a MVVM pattern where Add and Display is working fine for me, but i try to create a update option, but i have problem with picker, because method SelectedItem is used to binding new data and i don't know how to pass picker item from display to edit tab.

Update function from my displaydataviewmodel.cs where a selectedDungeon is passing from dungeondisplay.xaml.cs.

```
        public async void UpdateDungeon()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> newParm = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            newParm.Add("DungeonDetails", selectedDungeon);
            await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(UpdateDungeonPage),newParm);
        }
```

Listview from dungeondisplay.xaml

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding dungeonsCollection}"
                  IsRefreshing="True"
                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.Header>
                <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                    <Label Text="Name" />
                    <Label Text="Level" />
                    <Label Text="Enchant" />
                    <Label Text="Zone" />
                    <Label Text="Type" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Dungeon">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="15">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding level}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding enchant}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding zone}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding type}" />
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

ItemSelected from dungeondisplaypage.xaml.cs

```
    public void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _viewModel.selectedDungeon = args.SelectedItem as Dungeon;
    }
```

Picker where i wanna have a passed data UpdateDungeonPage.xaml

```
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding TierList}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Tier}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTier}"
             />
```

UpdateDungeonViewModel.cs

```
    [QueryProperty(nameof(DungeonDetails), "DungeonDetails")]
    public partial class UpdateDungeonPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Dungeon _dungeonDetails = new Dungeon();

        private readonly IDungeonService _service;

        public List<DungeonTier> TierList { get; set; }

        public List<DungeonEnchant> EnchantList { get; set; }

        public UpdateDungeonPageViewModel(IDungeonService dungeonService)
        {
            _service = dungeonService;

            TierList = new List<DungeonTier>();
            TierList.Add(new DungeonTier() { Id = 0, Tier = "4" });
            TierList.Add(new DungeonTier() { Id = 1, Tier = "5" });
            TierList.Add(new DungeonTier() { Id = 2, Tier = "6" });
            TierList.Add(new DungeonTier() { Id = 3, Tier = "7" });
            TierList.Add(new DungeonTier() { Id = 4, Tier = "8" });

            EnchantList = new List<DungeonEnchant>();
            EnchantList.Add(new DungeonEnchant() { Id = 0, Enchant = 0 });
            EnchantList.Add(new DungeonEnchant() { Id = 1, Enchant = 1 });
            EnchantList.Add(new DungeonEnchant() { Id = 2, Enchant = 2 });
            EnchantList.Add(new DungeonEnchant() { Id = 3, Enchant = 3 });

            
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        private DungeonTier _level;


        public DungeonTier SelectedTier
        {
            get { return Level; }
            set
            {
                Level = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        [ObservableProperty]
        private DungeonEnchant _enchant;

        public DungeonEnchant SelectedEnchant
        {
            get { return Enchant; }
            set
            {
                Enchant = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        [RelayCommand]
        public async void UpdateDungeon()
        {
            DungeonDetails.enchant = Enchant.Enchant;

            DungeonDetails.level = Level.Tier;


            int respone = -1;
            if (DungeonDetails.id > 0)
            {
                respone = await _service.UpdateItemAsync(DungeonDetails);
            }
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
}
```

I try with SelectedIndex method and i found, a solution but it work only on int and probably is not the best option.

EDIT : full content of DungeonDisplay.xaml.cs

```
protected DungeonDisplayViewModel _viewModel;

    public DungeonDisplay(DungeonDisplayViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    public void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _viewModel.selectedDungeon = args.SelectedItem as Dungeon;
    }


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.GetDungeonList();
    }
```

EDIT 2 : DungeonDisplayViewModel.cs

```
 public ObservableCollection<Dungeon> dungeonsCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dungeon>();

        private readonly IDungeonService _service;

        public Dungeon selectedDungeon { get; set; } = new Dungeon();

        public DungeonDisplayViewModel(IDungeonService dungeonService) 
        {
            _service = dungeonService;


        }


        [RelayCommand]
        public async void GetDungeonList()
        {
            var dungeonList = await _service.GetAllAsync();

            if (dungeonList?.Count > 0 )
            {
                dungeonsCollection.Clear();

                foreach( var dungeon in dungeonList )
                {
                    dungeonsCollection.Add(dungeon);
                }
            }
        }



        [RelayCommand]
        public async void AddDungeon()
        {
            await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AddDungeonPage));
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void UpdateDungeon()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> newParm = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            newParm.Add("DungeonDetails", selectedDungeon);
            await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(UpdateDungeonPage),newParm);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is this: "_viewModel.selectedDungeon"?

Comment: its assign actually selected dungeon to object Dungeon in viewmodel and after assign all values from this object.

Comment: Where is this defined in the ViewModel? What is the line of code?

Comment: I add full content of this file in edit.

Comment: I do not see: DungeonDisplayViewModel.cs

Comment: okey, i misunderstood, now is in edit 2

Comment: If you are trying to associate to an "id" within a given "selectedItem", you MAY need to take a look into other binding properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-use-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath-and-selecteditem?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 of SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath

Comment: I am try to have actual SelectedItem method and have option to assign it on load a page to update records. @DRapp its documentation for wpf with .net framework, but i use .net maui and don't see this funcionality.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to `UpdateDungeon()` and see if hit it?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT UpdateDungeon() is working, but i don;t know how to pass model better, because if i use actual method queryproperty pass the model after loading viewmodel. Idk how to say it so i create diagram maybe it better will show better https://imgur.com/a/xwuErwA

Answer (score 1):

According to your described needs, you can refer to the official doc of Xamarin.Forms: [Create a Xamarin.Forms application quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/app?pivots=windows). For convenience, you can directly generate the entire code for this example by this steps:

1. Launch Visual Studio 2022, and in the start window click Create a
   new    project to create a new project.
2. In the Create a new project window, select Mobile in the Project type drop-down, select the Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) template, and click the Next button.
3. In the Configure your new project window, set the Project name to Notes, choose a suitable location for the project, and click the Create button.
4. In the **New Mobile App** dialog, [select the **Flyout** template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK47m.jpg), and click the Create button. The entire code of the example will be automatically generated.

This example implements data display and addition functions. On this basis, I added the function of data update.

In ItemDetailPage, I add a button for updating data:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp3.Views.ItemDetailPage"
             Title="ItemDetailPage">
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
        
        <!-- add a btn -->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

At the same time, `ItemDetailViewModel` also needs to add a Command:

```
        ....
        public Command UpdateCommand { get; }
        public ItemDetailViewModel()
        {
            UpdateCommand = new Command(onUpdate);
        }
        private async void onUpdate()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(UpdateItemPage)}?{nameof(UpdateItemViewModel.ItemId)}={ItemId}");
        }
        .....
```

Next is UpdateItemPage and UpdateItemViewModel, both of which are based on NewItemPage and NewItemViewModel.

UpdateItemPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp3.Views.UpdateItemPage"
             Title="UpdateItemPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="3" Padding="15">
            <Label Text="Text" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Editor Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoSize="TextChanges" FontSize="Medium" Margin="0" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                <Button Text="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

UpdateItemViewModel.cs:

```
namespace MauiApp3.ViewMoels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
    public class UpdateItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string itemId;
        private string text;
        private string description;
        public string Id { get; set; }

       public UpdateItemViewModel()
        {
            UpdateCommand = new Command(OnUpdate, ValidateSave);
            CancelCommand = new Command(OnCancel);
            this.PropertyChanged +=
                (_, __) => UpdateCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        }
        private bool ValidateSave()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
                && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description);
        }

       public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
        }

       public string Description
        {
            get => description;
            set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
        }

       public Command UpdateCommand { get; }
       public Command CancelCommand { get; }

       private async void OnCancel()
        {
            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }

       private async void OnUpdate()
        {
            var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
            item.Text = Text;
            item.Description = Description;

            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }

       public string ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemId;
            }
            set
            {
                itemId = value;
                LoadItemId(value);
            }
        }

       public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
                Id = item.Id;
                Text = item.Text;
                Description = item.Description;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't worry it's Xamarin.Forms project, you can directly copy and paste these codes into MAUI. And this is [my effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibEjR.jpg).

Hope this is a workaround for you.

Comment: I m not at home so i cannot try this method, but i see you pass and use id to set all values and i pass full model, so i have question. Why you dont use a ObservableProperty and OnPropertyChange? and it a better to use Id to serach value instead of model?

Comment: @Rafalekvx *Why you dont use a ObservableProperty and OnPropertyChange?*  
 BaseViewModel class has implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  *it a better to use Id to serach value instead of model?*  This depends on the specific situation.  For my sample, I search value by [this](https://imgur.com/a/m60g5j5) in MockDataStore.cs

Comment: I try it today, but still have same problem, value from ItemId is no passing to UpdateItemViewModel. It was something like ItemId have value but after go to UpdateItemPage QueryProperty is skiped and none value is set

Comment: @Rafalekvx Are you missing some code? It works well for me. Could you upload the code sample to GitHub so that I can see what's wrong.

Comment: Probobly i miss something or wrong implement. Okey https://github.com/Rafalekvx/MVVMTest

Comment: @Rafalekvx I tested the code, but got this [error](https://imgur.com/a/qtt9IND). In addition, I also upload [my code](https://github.com/summer-004/MauiApp3) to GitHub. Wish it can help you.

Comment: I change my code more similar to your so all views was parameterless maybe now it work for you.  I m also have some question to your code because i m learning from courses and tutorials and tutors usually use communitytoolkit and you don't use it was a better habit to don't use this tools? You create interface with <T> i never see interface created like that, how it works and this implement was better then my? Also you don't use a constructors with value like service it better to have parameterless constructor?

Comment: @Rafalekvx *usually use communitytoolkit and you don't use it was a better habit to don't use this tools?*  Using the toolkit will be more concise and convenient, such as ObservableObject.  *You create interface with <T> i never see interface created like that, how it works and this implement was better then my?* Use a generic data type T as a placeholder, waiting to be replaced with an actual type when instantiated. For me, actual type is [`MockDataStore : IDataStore<Item>`](https://github.com/summer-004/MauiApp3/blob/main/Services/MockDataStore.cs#L5).

Comment: *Also you don't use a constructors with value like service it better to have parameterless constructor?*  This is hard to say, it needs to be analyzed on a case-by-case basis. Neither is better or worse. Like [this](https://imgur.com/a/TB16EcM).